# Get exact age of person, depends on month and date, not only year

Tags: javascript, algorithm, date

```js
 function test(val) {
     year = parseInt(val.slice(0,2)); // get year
     month = parseInt(val.slice(2,4)); // get month
     date = val.slice(4,6); // get date

     if (month > 40) { // For people born after 2000, 40 is added to the month.
         year += 2000;
         month -= 40;
     } else {
         year += 1900;
     }

    date = new Date(year, month-1, date, 0, 0);
    date_now = new Date();

   var diff =(date_now.getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000;
   diff /= (60 * 60 * 24);
   diff = Math.abs(Math.floor(diff/365.25));

   console.log(diff);

}

test("940911") // Should return 25
test("940910") // Should return 26
test("940909") // Should return 26
```

So If I'm born **1994.09.11** function **should returns 25**, Because 09.11 is tommorrow, but if I'm born at **1994.09.09**, It should **returns 26**, because 09.09 was yesterday. I do not want to use libreries like moment.js etc.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: It's probably not the problem (whatever the problem is), but that code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare your variables. Not declaring them, in loose mode, makes them globals.

Comment: All of your tests return what they should, based on your comments.

Comment: @NathanChampion - That's interesting. I get 26, 26, 26, not 25, 26, 26. What timezone are you in? I'm in British Summer Time (GMT+01:00).

Comment: I also get 26 26 26

Comment: @T.J.Crowder (GMT-5) Central Daylight Time https://i.imgur.com/5iohNaK.png

Comment: Why did you post this question again? Your previous question was closed as duplicate, and so should this one. Please don't repost. Instead edit your original question to make it suitable for reopening, or just use one of the many solutions in the referenced Q&A -- don't only look at the answer that was marked accepted.

Comment: Why `if (month > 40)`? There are [plenty of existing questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+difference+between+dates+in+years%2C+months%2C+days) about getting the difference between two dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution, anyway I suggest you to use moment.

So what about this solution?

Anyway the year? If 01 is 1901 or 2001 ?

```js
function test(d){
        let year = 1900+parseInt(d.slice(0,2)); 
    let month = parseInt(d.slice(2,4)); 
    let day = d.slice(4,6); 
        let yearNow = new Date().getFullYear();
    let monthNow = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    let dayNow = new Date().getDate();
    if (monthNow === month && dayNow < day || monthNow < month) {
      return yearNow - year - 1;
    } else {
      return yearNow - year;
    }
}
console.log(test("940911"))
console.log(test("940910"))
console.log(test("940909"))
```

Comment: It looks that works. I will do some tests and approve your answer if they pass. About years.. I have special condition if year is 01 and and month is over 40 it is 2000, otherwise it is 1900, But this does not apply to the task.

Comment: OK but here is a problem. 940911 is 1994-09-11 in dd/mm/yyyy is 11/09/1994 ? I don't understand the 40 months